# Opencart - mySQL cart entry is updated every time a page loads. Where is the method?

Tags: php, mysql, session, opencart, cart

Quick question for you today. I am running an Opencart website, and in the `customer` table there is a column titled `cart` which is a serialized array that stores the users' cart contents i.e.: `a:2:{i:92;i:2;i:12;i:3}`. Every time a new page on the site is loaded (it could be the home page, the account page; any page), that `cart` database entry is updated from the session data (basically, the session variable holds the cart contents, and then the contents transfer to the database every page load).

***Could you point me to the direction where this method exists AND where it is called?***

Comment: There's not really a single method for DB insertion .. you have to get the data that you want to insert somehow.  Are you asking for the entire block of code that does all of that?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Are you planning on removing it? Are you getting traffic spikes or are you wasting time on over optimisation?

Comment: Dealing with mobile/desktop session conflicts. I want to save a part of the user's session in the database that way when the `cart` database entry is changed inside my mobile application, it won't get overwritten if the user happens to be on the site logged and clicks on a new page, which would overwrite the `cart` database entry with the website session data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/system/library/customer.php` has the code in it that you are looking for. It contains all of the possibilities for this (loads when logging in, saves with each page load, and saves to db on logout)

Comment: Is it the construct that gets called every time a page loads?

Comment: Yes (on the catalog side of your site - admin the class is not loaded)